# Understanding why some conditions are necessary for Bayesian-Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, bayesian, nash-equilibrium

Consider the following static game:

- All random vectors below are defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$
- Players' beliefs coincide with $P$
- $n$ players
- Players indexed by $i\in \{1,...,n\}$
- $J_i$ is player $i$'s information set; $J_i$ is a random vector with support $\mathcal{J}_i$
- $\mathcal{D}_i$ is player $i$'s action space
- $s_i: \mathcal{J}_i \rightarrow \mathcal{D}_i$ is player $i$'s strategy
- $D_i=s_i(J_i)$ is player $i$'s action, with support $\mathcal{D}_i$ (pure strategies)
- When playing player  $i$ cares about other predetermined features $Z_i$; $Z_i$ is a random vector with support $\mathcal{Z}_i$
- $\pi: \mathcal{D}_i \times \mathcal{D}_{-i}\times \mathcal{Z}_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is player $i$'s profit function

At this point, the book I am reading claims that the condition $(\star)$ below is a **necessary condition** for Bayesian-Nash equilibrium:

If $s_i$ is the strategy played by player $i$, then 
$$ (\star) \hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\Big(\pi(D_i, D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big| J_i, D_i=s_i(J_i)\Big)  \geq  & \sup_{d\in \mathcal{D}_i} \mathbb{E}\Big(\pi(D_i, D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big|  J_i, D_i=d\Big)\\
&\text{ a.s. } J_i
\end{aligned}
$$
$\forall i \in \{1,...,n\}$, where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes the expectation.

**Question:** Why $(\star)$ is just necessary for Bayesian-Nash equilibrium? Isn't it the definition of Bayesian-Nash equilibrium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supremum is only being taken over the pure strategies (assuming that where you wrote $d\in D_i$ it's supposed to say $d\in\mathcal D_i$, since $d\in D_i$ makes no sense). In the definition, the supremum is taken over all strategies, including mixed strategies. (Also, in the definition, you have $=$ instead of $\ge$, since in that case the left-hand side is one of the things that the right-hand side takes the supremum over and thus can't be greater.)

Comment: Thanks a lot: 1) I have edited the typo on $D_i$ versus $\mathcal{D}_i$; 2) Suppose I assume that agents only play pure strategies: how does your answer change? Thank you

Comment: @STF: I'm not sure what it would mean to assume that. We're no longer talking about a Bayesian Nash equilibrium then. The original question and answer were about a Bayesian Nash equilibrium, so my answer would no longer make sense then. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: I'm confused about the way in which the game is described and how to reconcile it with the standard way to introduce BNE. Usually BNE is explained by saying that each player $i$ is assigned a type $\theta_i$ and the strategy of player $i$ is a function of $\theta_i$, $s_i(\theta_i)$. Moreover, players know their own type only.

Comment: Hence, we can define the best response set of player $i$ for a given $s_{-i}$ and $\theta_i$ as $BR_i(s_i, \theta_i)\equiv argmax_{s_i} \sum_{\theta_{-i}} p(\theta_i|\theta_{-i}) \pi (s_i(\theta_i), s_{-i}(\theta_{-i}))$ where $p(\theta_{-i}|\theta_i) $ is the probability that the other players are of type $\theta_{-i}$ given that player $i$ is of type $\theta_i$. Therefore, $s$ is BNE if and only if $i\in BR_i(s_{-i}, \theta_i)$ $\forall i$ $\forall \theta \equiv (\theta_i)_{\forall i}$.

Comment: In my question, the game is described in a completely different way and I don't understand how to reconcile it with the "usual" setting.

Comment: That is probably the source of my total confusion. With respect to what is taken the expectation in $(\star)$?

Comment: @STF: I'm not familiar with this presentation, either. I figured that the player's type is encoded in the random $J_i$.

Comment: could you help me with this other question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847928/implications-of-pure-strategy-bayesian-nash-equilibrium Thank you very much