# Implications of Pure Strategy Bayesian Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, bayesian, nash-equilibrium

Consider the following simultaneous move game:

- All random vectors below are defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$
- Players' compute expectations correctly using $P$
- $n$ players
- Players indexed by $i\in \{1,...,n\}$
- $\text{I}_i$ is player $i$'s information set; $\text{I}_i$ is a random vector with support $\mathcal{I}_i$; $I\equiv (\text{I}_1,..., \text{I}_n)\equiv (\text{I}_i, \text{I}_{-i})$
- $\mathcal{D}_i$ is player $i$'s action space
- $s_i: \mathcal{I}_i \rightarrow \mathcal{D}_i$ is player $i$'s strategy (we assume that **only pure strategies are possible**)
- $D_i=s_i(\text{I}_i)$ is player $i$'s action, with support $\mathcal{D}_i$
- When playing, player  $i$ cares about other pre-determined features $Z_i$; $Z_i$ is a random vector with support $\mathcal{Z}_i$
- $\pi: \mathcal{D}_i \times \mathcal{D}_{-i}\times \mathcal{Z}_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is player $i$'s profit function

---

The equilibrium concept is pure strategy Bayesian Nash equilibrium (PSBNE)
defined as follows: player $i$'s best response set given $\text{I}_i, s_{-i}$ is defined as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{BR}_i(\text{I}_i, s_{-i}) &\equiv \text{argmax}_{s_{i}} {E}_{\text{I}_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), s_{-i}(\text{I}_{-i}), Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, s_i, s_{-i} \Big)
\end{aligned}
$$
(assume $\max$ exists for simplicity; ${E}$ denotes expectation and the subscript of $E$ clarifies with respect to which random variables we are taking the expectation)

Hence, $s\equiv (s_1,..., s_n)$ is a PSBNE if
$$
s_i(\text{I}_i)\in \text{BR}_i(\text{I}_i, s_{-i}) \text{ }\forall i \in \mathcal{N} \text{, a.s. } \text{I}
$$
or, equivalently, if 
$$
\begin{aligned}
 {E}_{\text{I}_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), s_{-i}(\text{I}_{-i}), Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, s_i, s_{-i} \Big) \geq \max_{\tilde{s}_i}   & {E}_{\text{I}_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(\tilde{s}_i(\text{I}_i), s_{-i}(\text{I}_{-i}), Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, \tilde{s}_i, s_{-i} \Big) \\
 &\forall i \in \mathcal{N} \text{, a.s. } \text{I}
 \end{aligned}
$$ 
(Notice that a PSBNE may not exist or there may be more than one PSBNE)

---

A book I am reading claims at this point that a NECESSARY CONDITION FOR PSBNE is that

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\star)\text{ }{E}_{D_i, D_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(D_i, D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big|   \text{I}_i \Big) \geq \max_{\tilde{d}\in \mathcal{D}_i}   {E}_{D_{-i},Z_i}\Big(& \pi(\tilde{d}, D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i \Big)\\
& \forall i \in \mathcal{N} \text{, a.s. } \text{I}_i
 \end{aligned}
$$

---

**Question: Why is that the case?** A proof may be the following

(1) If $s_i$ denotes PSBNE played by player $i$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
  &E_{D_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, s_i \Big) \\
  &\geq \max_{d\in \mathcal{D}_i}    E_{D_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(D_i, D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, D_i=d\Big) \text{ } \forall s_i\text{, }\text{ a.s. } \text{I}_i 
 \end{aligned}
$$
$$
\Updownarrow
$$ 
$$
\begin{aligned}
  &E_{D_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, s_i) \Big) \\
  &\geq    E_{D_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(D_i, D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, D_i=d\Big)  \text{ }\forall d \in \mathcal{D}_i\text{, }\forall s_i\text{, }\text{ a.s. }  \text{I}_i 
 \end{aligned}
$$
$$
\Updownarrow
$$ 
$$
\begin{aligned}
  &\sum_{d_{-i}, z_i} \Big[ \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), d_{-i}, z_i)\times \mathbb{P}(D_{-i}=d_{-i}, Z_i=z_i| \text{I}_i, s_i) \\
  &\hspace{-1.2cm}-  \pi(d, d_{-i}, z_i)\times \mathbb{P}(D_{-i}=d_{-i}, Z_i=z_i| \text{I}_i, D_i=d) \Big]\geq 0 \text{ }\forall d \in \mathcal{D}_i\text{, }\forall s_i\text{, }\text{ a.s. }  \text{I}_i 
 \end{aligned}
$$

(2) By simultaneity of interactions and by the fact that $Z_i$ is assigned prior to the game, $(D_{-i}, Z_i)| \text{I}_i, D_i \sim (D_{-i}, Z_i)| \text{I}_i$, so that above becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
  &\sum_{d_{-i}, z_i} \Big[ \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), d_{-i}, z_i)\times \mathbb{P}(D_{-i}=d_{-i}, Z_i=z_i| \text{I}_i) \\
  &-  \pi(d, d_{-i}, z_i)\times \mathbb{P}(D_{-i}=d_{-i}, Z_i=z_i| \text{I}_i) \Big]\geq 0 \text{ }\forall d \in \mathcal{D}_i\text{, }\forall s_i\text{, } \text{ a.s. } \text{I}_i 
 \end{aligned}
$$
$$
\Updownarrow
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
  &\sum_{d_{-i}, z_i} \Big[ \overbrace{(\pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), d_{-i}, z_i)-  \pi(d, d_{-i}, z_i))}^{\equiv\Delta \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), d, d_{-i}, z_i)}\\
  & \times \mathbb{P}(D_{-i}=d_{-i}, Z_i=z_i| \text{I}_i)\Big]\geq 0 \text{ }\forall d \in \mathcal{D}_i\text{, }\forall s_i\text{, } \text{ a.s.} \text{I}_i 
 \end{aligned}
$$

(3) Multiplying by $\mathbb{P}(D_i=s_i(\text{I}_i)| \text{I}_i)>0$, above becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
  &\sum_{d_{-i}, z_i} \Big[ \Delta \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), d, d_{-i}, z_i) \times \mathbb{P}(D_{-i}=d_{-i}, Z_i=z_i| \text{I}_i) \Big] \\& \times \mathbb{P}(D_i=s_i(\text{I}_i)| \text{I}_i)  \geq 0  \text{ }\forall d \in \mathcal{D}_i\text{, }\forall s_i\text{, }\text{ a.s.} \text{I}_i 
 \end{aligned}
$$

(4) Summing over $s_i$, above implies
$$
\begin{aligned}
  &\sum_{s_i, d_{-i}, z_i} \Big[ \Delta \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), d, d_{-i}, z_i) \times \mathbb{P}(D_{-i}=d_{-i}, Z_i=z_i| \text{I}_i)  \\  & \times \mathbb{P}(D_i=s_i(\text{I}_i)| \text{I}_i) \Big] \geq 0  \text{ }\forall d \in \mathcal{D}_i\text{, }\text{ a.s. }\text{I}_i 
 \end{aligned}
$$

(5) By conditional independence, above becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{s_i, d_{-i}, z_i} \Big[ \Delta \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), d, d_{-i}, z_i) \\
&\times \mathbb{P}(D_i=s_i(\text{I}_i), D_{-i}=d_{-i}, Z_i=z_i| \text{I}_i)  \Big] \geq 0  \text{ }\forall d \in \mathcal{D}_i\text{, } \text{ a.s. } \text{I}_i 
 \end{aligned}
$$
$$
\Updownarrow
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
&E_{D_i, D_{-i}, Z_i} (\Delta \pi(D_i, d, D_{-i}, Z_i) | \text{I}_i) \geq 0  \text{ }\forall d \in \mathcal{D}_i\text{, }\text{ a.s. } \text{I}_i 
 \end{aligned}
$$

Of this proof what I'm not convinced about is the first claim: 
If $s_i$ denotes PSBNE played by player $i$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
  &E_{D_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, s_i \Big) \\
  &\geq \max_{d\in \mathcal{D}_i}    E_{D_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(D_i, D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, D_i=d\Big) \text{ } \forall s_i\text{, }  \text{ a.s. }\text{I}_i
 \end{aligned}
$$
This is not the definition of PSBNE, where we also condition on $s_{-i}$, and it does not even seem necessary for it! In other words
$$E_{D_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), D_{-i}, Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, s_i \Big)\neq E_{I_{-i},Z_i}\Big( \pi(s_i(\text{I}_i), s_{-i}(I_{-i}), Z_i)\Big| \text{I}_i, s_i, s_{-i} \Big)
$$

Comment: Isn't that just the [monoticity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Monotonicity)? If the inequality holds for every $d$, it also holds when we form the expectation over $d$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @joriki I have tried to add some more thoughts, thank you